# Doctrine, key offset, "JOIN bar b ON f.id = b.id - 1"

Tags: doctrine, dql

The database I work with has an offset on one of the table's key. In plain SQL this would look like:

`SELECT * FROM foo f LEFT JOIN bar b ON f.id = b.id - 1`

I tried to use `Expr\Join::ON` with `QueryBuilder`, but that gives me an error saying that `Expected end of string, got 'ON'`. Example below.

I also tried `Expr\Join::WITH` with `QueryBuilder`, but that returns nothing for that join. In other words, `$element->getBar()` returns null. Example below.

I cannot modify the database structure or data. I have to work with it as it is.

Example of `QueryBuilder` usage:

```
return $this
  ->createQueryBuilder('f')
  ->select('f, b')
  ->leftJoin('f.bar', 'b', Expr\Join::ON, 'f.id = b.id - 1');
  // ->leftJoin('f.bar', 'b', Expr\Join::WITH, 'f.id = b.id - 1');
```

Comment: Can you show how are you using the query builder in your code?

Comment: @IonBazan, I added example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine 2 JOIN ON error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939148/doctrine-2-join-on-error)

Comment: @IonBazan, no, guy there had problem with custom names.